# unix shell: replace by dictionary

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have file which contains some data, like this

```
2011-01-02 100100 1 
2011-01-02 100200 0
2011-01-02 100199 3
2011-01-02 100235 4
```

and have some "dictionary" in separate file

```
100100 Event1
100200 Event2
100199 Event3
100235 Event4
```

and I know that

```
0 - warning
1 - error
2 - critical
etc...
```

I need some script with sed/awk/grep or something else which helps me receive data like this

```
100100 Event1 Error
100200 Event2 Warning
100199 Event3 Critical
etc
```

will be grateful for ideas how to do this in best way, or for working example

**update**

sometimes I have data like this

```
2011-01-02 100100 1
2011-01-02 sometext 100200 0
2011-01-02 100199 3
2011-01-02 sometext 100235 4
```

where sometext = any 6 characters (maybe this is helpful info)

in this case I need whole data:

```
2011-01-02 sometext EventNameFromDictionary Error
```

or without "sometext"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
 lvl[0] = "warning"
 lvl[1] = "error"
 lvl[2] = "critical"
 }
NR == FNR {
  evt[$1] = $2; next
  } 
{
  print $2, evt[$2], lvl[$3]
  }' dictionary infile
```

Comment: woah too much power. NR = FNR?; only flaw is the relatively useless way it deals with non-existing lookup keys.

Comment: thanks, very good example, it's what I need.


If somebody have another ideas - will be grateful (I will use them for self-education)

Comment: @sehe, NR == FNR evaluates to true only while reading the first non-empty input file (the dictionary in this case). As far as the non-existing keys are concerned, the OP mentioned 1, 2 ... etc, so I assumed they were all existing keys. It could be easily be fixed with `$2 in evt ? evt[$2] : $2 ...`

Comment: how I can update that script if sometimes I have more columns in INFILE? In example there are 3 columns, but in real data sometimes I have 4 columns (second column after the date column), and in that case I got only first column as result

Comment: @Vitaliy,
please post sample input and example of the desired output.

Comment: @Dimitre Radoulov, In real INFILE I have data like this "2011-01-02 eventname 100100 1", with ur script I transform it to desired format "2011-01-02 eventname EventCodeFromDictoionary Error". But sometimes "eventname" contains two words. for example "2011-01-02 eventnamepart1 eventnamepart2 100100 1" and in this case I want receive all columns or without second column (eventnamepart1) in case if INFILE string contains 5 columns.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this replacement by dictionary really work? I am trying it on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600278/replacement-by-dictionary-possible-with-awk-or-sed) but problems with one-to-one mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new answer for the new requirement and because of the limited formatting options inside a comment:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
 lvl[0] = "warning"
 lvl[1] = "error"
 lvl[2] = "critical"
 }
NR == FNR {
  evt[$1] = $2; next
  } 
{
  if (NF > 3) {
    idx = 3; $1 = $1 OFS $2
    }
  else idx = 2  
  print $1, $idx in evt ? \
    evt[$idx] : $idx, $++idx in lvl ? \
      lvl[$idx] : $idx
  }' dictionary infile
```

You won't need to escape the new lines inside the tertiary operator if you're using *GNU awk*.

Some awk implementations may have problems with this part:

```
$++idx in lvl ? lvl[$idx] : $idx
```

If you're using one of those, 
change it to:

```
$(idx + 1) in lvl ? lvl[$(idx + 1)] : $(idx + 1)
```

OK, comments added:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
 lvl[0] = "warning"       # map the error levels
 lvl[1] = "error"                
 lvl[2] = "critical"      
 }                        
NR == FNR {               # while reading the first
                          # non-empty input file
  evt[$1] = $2          # build the associative array evt
  next                    # skip the rest of the program
                          # keyed by the value of the first column
                          # the second column represents the values
  }                       
{                         # now reading the rest of the input
  if (NF > 3) {           # if the number of columns is greater than 3
    idx = 3               # set idx to 3 (the key in evt)
    $1 = $1 OFS $2       # and merge $1 and $2
    }                     
  else idx = 2            # else set idx to 2
  print $1, \              # print the value of the first column
    $idx in evt ? \    # if the value of the second (or the third,
                  \       # depeneding on the value of idx), is an existing
                  \       # key in the evt array, print its value
    evt[$idx] : $idx, \ # otherwise print the actual column value
    $++idx in lvl ?   \   # the same here, but first increment the idx 
     lvl[$idx] : $idx       # because we're searching the lvl array now     
  }' dictionary infile
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but make me crazy )) I have tried to test it with another number of columns, and didn't understand the principle. In any case - thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have simplify it, and it's meet my criteria now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope perl is ok too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(DICT, 'dict.txt') or die;
my %dict = %{{ map { my ($id, $name) = split; $id => $name } (<DICT>) }};
close(DICT);

my %level = ( 0 => "warning", 
              1 => "error",
              2 => "critical" );

open(EVTS, 'events.txt') or die;

while (<EVTS>)
{
    my ($d, $i, $l) = split;
    $i = $dict{$i}  || $i;  # lookup
    $l = $level{$l} || $l;  # lookup 
    print "$d\t$i\t$l\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.pl
2011-01-02      Event1  error
2011-01-02      Event2  warning
2011-01-02      Event3  3
2011-01-02      Event4  4
```

Comment: I prefer shell only, but thanks for help, I'll save it for my future research

Comment: Soooo... when did awk, sed, grep become 'shell'? I understand you, but calling it 'shell only' is a misnomer