# data comparison in two files

Tags: shell, unix

I have two tab-delimited files.

File 1 (10 rows and say 4 columns, these columns might not be filled in each row):

```
Chra stra stpa NM1 NM2 NR1
Chrb strb stpb NR2 NM1
```

File 2 (25 rows and 3 columns):

```
Tg NM1 12
Tg NM3 3
Tg NR1 76
```

Now what I want to do, is to compare the NM and NR identifiers in present each row of file 1 to file 2i f anywhere in file2 NR identifier matches. It should extract the corresponding value of NR/NM identifier from file 2.

File 3 may look like this (say for NM1):

```
chra stra stpa NM1 12
chra stra stpa NR1 76
```

Any suggestions for a shell script?

Comment: possible duplication of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385609/unix-shell-replace-by-dictionary

Comment: in this file1 number of columns are not fixed in each row ...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ join -1 4 -2 2 \
<(for i in 4 5 6 7; do join -e _ -j $i f1 f1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,0; done |
  sed '/_$/d' | sort -k4,4) \
<(sort -k2,2 f2) \
-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,0,2.3

Chra stra stpa NM1 12
Chrb strb stpb NM1 12
Chra stra stpa NR1 76
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than shell script, I'd do this kind of thing with a Perl script. You can use the split() function to get an array with all the "fields" for each line, and it's downhill from there. No need to think up a fancy regular expression. [Here](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html)'s 
an example of doing this kind of thing:

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {tag[$2] = $3; next}
    {
        # determine if this line has a "NR" tag from file2
        have_nr = 0
        for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i ~ /^NR/ && $i in tag) {
                have_nr = 1
                break
            }
        }

        # if it does have a matching NR tag, then
        # print the tag value for every matching NR/NM tag
        if (have_nr) {
            for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {
                if ($i in tag) {
                    print $1, $2, $3, $i, tag[$i]
                }
            }
        }
    }

' file2 file1
```