# kind of tranpose needed of a file with inconsistent number of columns in each row

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a tab delimited file (in which number of columns in each row is not fixed) which looks like this:

```
chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_024813 NM_053274
```

I want to have a file from this in following order (first three columns are identifiers which I need it while splitting it)

```
chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_024813
chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_053274
```

Suggestions for a shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    IFS='   '
    while read a b c rest
    do
        for fld in $rest
        do
            echo -e "$a\t$b\t$c\t$fld"
        done
    done
}
```

Note that you should enter a real tab there (`IFS`)

I also thought I should do a perl version:

```
#!/bin/perl -n
($a,$b,$c,@r)=(chomp and split /\t/); print "$a\t$b\t$c\t$_\n" for @r
```

To do it all from the commandline, reading from in.txt and outputting to out.txt:

```
perl -ne '($a,$b,$c,@r)=(chomp and split /\t/); print "$a\t$b\t$c\t$_\n" for @r' in.txt > out.txt
```

Of course if you save the perl script (say as script.pl)

```
perl script.pl in.txt > out.txt
```

If you also make the script file executable (`chmod +x script.pl`):

```
./script.pl in.txt > out.txt
```

HTH

Comment: how to get the output in a new file (for PERL version)?

Comment: `, map { print "$a\t$b\t$c\t$_\n" } @r` is better written as `; print "$a\t$b\t$c\t$_\n" for @r`

Comment: Upvoted for the perl version, that's a slick array reference! Isn't IFS redundant with using read on space delimited data? NM, he did say tab delimited. :P

Comment: @Christoffer: nice, agreed. (interesting how the sequence point needs to be a statement separator now... mmmm). I changed the answer for the simpler code. Thx

Comment: @sehe: Check out my new version. ;)

Comment: CAn u run this sample data and still get the same output (in my case it doesn't give the same output <br/> sample data is       chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_024813 NM_053274                     OutPut is                                                    chr1 92536437 92537640 
chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_024813
chr1 92536437 92537640 NM_053274

Comment: @Angelo: perhaps you should update the question, because that is not readable (oh and all solutions I tested all resulted in the correct output for the sample data. Does you sample data actually contain tab characters?)

Comment: @sehe: Please take the sample data in the question and run the script

Comment: this is what I am using right now: #!/bin/perl -n
($a,$b,$c,@r)=(chomp and split /\t/); print "$a\t$b\t$c\t$_\n" for @r

Comment: @sehe: may I have your email id I can send you the sample data and you may have a look at it. The script runs good for few number of items...once you run my sample you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: You can use `$'\t'` for a literal tab in bash to avoid any copy/paste transposition errors.

Comment: @Sorpigal: thanks! (and: "sigh..." there is a reason why I hate shell scripting. Why did they invent Yet Another Strange Quoting Scheme just for something as simple as a tab :) )

Comment: @Angelo: it is. For precisely the reason you demonstrate: Someone is bound to put it on the web, and I get enough spam :)

Comment: FWIW: since I don't think your file is _actually_ tab delimited, try T replacing `/\t/` by '/\s+/`. Cheers

Comment: @sehe the file is in fact tab delimited; I should know, it's produced as the output of a script that I wrote to process a file he has (this was the response to another question).

Answer (score 3):

Not shell, and the other answer is perfectly fine, but i onelined it in perl :

```
perl -F'/\s/' -lane '$,="\t"; print @F,$_ for splice @F,3' $FILE
```

**Edit**: New (even more unreadable ;) version, inspired by the other answers. Abusing perl's command line parameters and special variables for autosplitting and line ending handling.

Means: For each of the fields after the three first (`for splice @F,3`), print the first three and it (`print @F,$_`).

`-F` sets the field separator to `\s` (should be `\t`) for `-a` autosplitting into `@F`.

`-l` turns on line ending handling for `-n` which runs the `-e` code for each line of the input.

`$,` is the output field separator.

Comment: Me too. However, what is it with perl and regex abuse. I like my version heaps better. It's a oneliner too :)

Comment: Agreed, yours is nicer, not using a regexp.

Comment: Technically, of course, the `/\t/` is a re quoted pattern. However, that could be written `qq(\t)`, `"\t"` etc. I just like to remind myself `/visually/` that the split pattern is interpreted as a regex

Comment: Woot Woot. You won the archaic special vars competition; I'd wager `$,` can be a handy shorthand but only repais itself when there are many output lines using the same delimiter. Nice work nonetheless

Comment: @sehe: Removed `$,`, `join` is nicer. And now using `splice`. And thanks. :)

Comment: Very informative, Mr. Hammarström; thanks for all these creative hints. I have nack for remembering those so thank you (finding them is the hard part). `splice` is a gem

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

So you want to duplicate the first three columns for each remaining item?

```
$ cat File | while read X
      do PRE=$(echo "$X" | cut -f1-3 -d ' ')
      for Y in $(echo "$X" | cut -f4- -d ' ')
          do echo $PRE $Y >> OutputFilename
      done
  done
```

Returns:

```
chr 786 789 NM
chr 786 789 NR
chr 786 789 NT
chr 123 345 NR
```

This cuts the first three space delimited columns as a prefix, and then abuses the fact that a for loop will step through a space delimited list to call echo.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank's, how can I get this into a file.... shall I just put >filename in end ???????

Comment: The original was a one liner I tested on the command line, I added line breaks in lieu of ;'s for legibility. Careful how you convert that to a script.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a subset of your [data comparison in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387204/) question.

Extracting my slightly hacky solution from there:

```
for i in 4 5 6 7; do join -e _ -j $i f f -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,0; done | sed '/_$/d'
```