# replace text based on a dictionary

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

I need to do something similar to this post (but with a twist).  That is why I am asking.

[unix shell: replace by dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385609/unix-shell-replace-by-dictionary)

I have a dictionary(dict.txt).  It is space separated and it reads like this:

V7 Momentum

B6 Quanta

....

(the first column is key and the second column is value, in a sense)

I have a user file (user.txt), it contains the occurrences of the keys (V7, B6 etc).  The twist is that keys are not in its own column (so the method in the above post does not apply).

The user file (user.txt) can be view as a stream of characters. I just want to replace all occurrences of the keys (e.g., V7), regardless they are bounded by space or bounded by other character by the value (Momentum) looked up from the dictionary.

For example:

"We have V7 as input" --> should change to --> "We have Momentum as input"

"We have somethingV7_as input" -->should change to --> "We have somethingMomentum_as input"

Comment: sorry, the first line should be: "Dear AWK, SED, Perl gurus," somehow the first two words are missing

Comment: What kind of things have you already tried? What exactly are you stuck with? If you're looking for some implementation details, I'd say in perl it's possible to parse the dict.txt and put all of the keys/values into a hash and just have a regex go over each entry and replace key with value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usage: `awk -f foo.awk dict.dat user.dat`
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

```
NR == FNR {
  rep[$1] = $2
  next
} 

{
  for (key in rep)
    gsub(key, rep[key])
  print
}
```

Comment: Great! thank you so much.  I really should find time to learn this great tool ...

Answer (score 3):

As long as your dictionary keys contain nothing but alphanumeric characters, this Perl will do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'dict.txt' or die $!;
my %dict =  map { chomp; split ' ', $_, 2 } <$fh>;
my $re = join '|', keys %dict;

open $fh, '<', 'user.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  s/($re)/$dict{$1}/g;
  print;
}
```

Comment: If the dictionary has entries for both Abc and Abcd, which one takes precedence becomes arbitrary; it's better to sort longest first.  Also, non-alphanumerics are just a matter of quoting.  So: `$re = join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %dict`

Comment: Since all the keys in the question look like `/[A-Z][0-9]/` I chose to code for that. It seems perverse to cater for every possible complication when the evidence is that there are none.

Comment: It's no trouble to do it "right", and it's a question that comes up an awful lot...see https://www.google.com/search?q=join+map+quotemeta+sort+a+length+b+keys

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/./!d;s/\([^ ]*\) *\(.*\)/\\|\1|s||\2|g/' dict.txt | sed -f - user.txt
```