# Replacement by dictionary possible with AWK or Sed?

Tags: dictionary, awk, sed, substitution

You have a dictionary, Dictionary.txt, and an input file, inFile.txt. The dictionary tells you about possible translations. The solution to a similar problem in [unix shell: replace by dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385609/unix-shell-replace-by-dictionary) seems to hardcode things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6385673/164148) that I cannot fully understand. You can come up with better replacement technique than dictionary but AWK/Sed script should be able to read in multiple files, in the simplest case only one dictionary file and one infile.

**How to replace elegantly by dictionary with AWK or Sed?**

---

**Example**

> *Dictionary.txt*
>
> ```
> 1 one
> 2 two 
> 3 three
> four fyra
> five fem
> ```
>
> *inFile.txt*
>
> ```
> one 1 hello hallo 2 three hallo five five
> ```
>
> *Output from the Command, we are after for the command like `awk/sed {} Dictionary.txt inFile.txt`*
>
> ```
> one one hello hallo two three hallo fem fem
> ```
>
> *AWK example where specifically selected the replacements but one-one replacements not working.*
>
> ```
> awk 'BEGIN {
>  lvl[1] = "one"
>  lvl[2] = "two"
>  lvl[3] = "three"
>  # TODO: this does not work 
>  # lvl[four] = "fyra"
>  # lvl[five] = "fem"
>  # lvl[one] = "one"
>  # lvl["hello"] = "hello"
>  # lvl[hallo] = "hallo"
>  # lvl[three] = "three"
>  }
> NR == FNR {
>   evt[$1] = $2; next
>   }
> {
>    print $1, evt[$2], $3, $4, evt[$5], $6, $7, evt[$8], evt[$9]
>    #TODO: this dos not work, eg. one-one mapping   
>    #   print evt[$1], evt[$2], evt[$3], evt[$4], evt[$5], evt[$6], evt[$7], evt[$8], evt[$9]
>   }' dictionary.txt infile.txt
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i in map ? map[$i] : $i) } 1' fileA fileB
one one hello hallo two three hallo fem fem
```

Note that it will compress any chains of contiguous white space to a single blank char. Tell us if that is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

if you have gnu sed, it supports script-file with `-f`:

```
`-f SCRIPT-FILE'
`--file=SCRIPT-FILE'
     Add the commands contained in the file SCRIPT-FILE to the set of
     commands to be run while processing the input.
```

you could write your substitutions in "c.sed" for example,  then

```
sed -f c.sed file
```

example `c.sed`:

```
s/1/one/g
s/2/two/g
...
```

**EDIT**

just now you didn't tag the question with awk, sure, the awk one-liner would be simpler: (with your example)

```
awk '$1=$2' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "1 one
2 two 
3 three
four fyra
five fem"|awk '$1=$2'
one one
two two
three three
fyra fyra
fem fem
```

Comment: @hhh, the other file is column based too? I don't know how does your real "replaceRuleFile" look like. if there was some characters like `*,.,+[.....`, using regex to do replacement is not reliable.

Comment: +1 to counter the wanton downvote by the OP.  If your question was bad, don't punish the people who answered it.

Comment: +1 from my side for showing patience...

Comment: +1 when changed because upvoted similar answer -- even though this answer ignores the point about multiple input files, a thing I had in the very first edit.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

This answers the original post. doesn't answer the multiple times edited and restructured question...
on top of that I get a `-1` from the OP who asked this question... Damn!

Yes, much simpler in awk :

This will print both column as the value for the second column :

```
awk '{print $2, $2}' file
```

If you want to flip first with second column:

```
awk '{print $2, $1}' file
```

Comment: Yes, I did because I was following your original post and then you edited... This doesn't answer the edited question...

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I want -- my original question was misleadingly spelled -- now it should be clear -1 until corrected.

Comment: +1 to counter the wanton downvote by the OP.  If your question was bad, don't punish the people who answered it.

Comment: You don't realize in this answe that even the very original question had two input files, sorry you just did not read the question to the end.

Answer (score 3):

If `ReplaceLeftWithRight_where_you_do_not_replace_things.txt` contains pairs of string replacements, where any occurrence of the text in the first column should be replaced by the second column,

```
1 one
2 two 
3 three
four fyra
five fem
```

then this can trivially be expressed as a `sed` script.

```
s/1/one/g
s/2/two/g
s/3/three/g
s/four/fyra/g
s/five/fem/g
```

and you can trivially use `sed` to create this `sed` script:

```
sed 's%.*%s/&/g%;s% %/%' ReplaceLeftWithRight_where_you_do_not_replace_things.txt
```

then pass the output of that to a second instance of `sed`:

```
sed 's%.*%s/&/%;s% %/%' ReplaceLeftWithRight_where_you_do_not_replace_things.txt |
sed -f - someFile_Where_You_Replace_Things.txt
```

to replace all the matches in the file `someFile_Where_You_Replace_Things.txt` and have the output printed to standard output.

Sadly, not all `sed` dialects support the `-f -` option to read a script from standard input, but this should work at least on most Linuxes.

Sorry if I misunderstood your problem statement.

Comment: The SED thing is totally right idea but I feel AWK is simpler solution here because it works columnwise -- I used SED like that first on a small case but with a large case I feel it is too repetative, +1 for a good try!

Comment: Both the title and the tags imply that `sed` is acceptable.  Oh well.

Comment: Sure that is why +1 but I feel awk can do this somehow easier, `$ awk -f t '{index=$1 replace=$2}' END '{sub(replace,index) }' replace.txt` -- I need to somehow read the other file to buffer to store things to variables and then substitute($val, $ind, newfile) -- good training in trying to do things the simplest possible way :)

Comment: What's "repetative", anyway?  There is nothing repetitive in `sed 's%.*%s/&/%;s% %/%' file1 | sed -f - file2` as far as I can tell, unless you mean having two `sed` processes is repetitive.

Comment: +1 ... thanks for showing support and still provide an answer to this question...

Comment: @tripleee repetitive means that one needs to have many sed processes in using the `-f` flag. I am trying to find a simpler solution: I feel this requires better understanding in reading many input files in AWK and processing it, taking me some time to understand but well -- good training.

Comment: You'd need to make the sed script a bit smarter to avoid "fourteen" becoming "fyrateen", etc. unless of course that's the desired behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yeah, the first `sed` script could add word boundary markers `'s%.*%s/\\<&/g%;s% %\\>/%'`