# How to delete the string which is present in parameter from file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have redirected some string into one parameter for ex: `ab=jyoti,priya, pranit`
I have one file : **Name.txt** which contains -
`jyoti
prathmesh
John
Kelvin
pranit`

I want to delete the records from the Name.txt file which are contain in **ab** parameter.

Please suggest if this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ab` is a shell variable, you can easily turn it into an extended regular expression, and use it with `grep -E`:

```
grep -E -x -v "${ab//,/|}" Name.txt
```

The string substitution `${ab//,/|}` returns the value of `$ab` with every `,` substituted with a `|` which turns it into an extended regular expression, suitable for passing as an argument to `grep -E`.

The `-v` option says to remove matching lines.

The `-x` option specifies that the match needs to cover the whole input line, so that a short substring will not cause an entire longer line to be removed.  Without it, `ab=prat` would cause `pratmesh` to be removed.

If you really require a `sed` solution, the transformation should be fairly trivial.  `grep -E -v -x 'aaa|bbb|ccc'` is equivalent to `sed '/^\(aaa\|bbb\|ccc)$/d'` (with some dialects disliking the backslashes, and others requiring them).

To do an in-place edit (modify `Name.txt` without a temporary file), try this:

```
sed -i "/^\(${ab//,/\|}\)\$/d" Name.txt
```

This is not entirely robust against strings containing whitespace or other shell metacharacters, but if you just need

Comment: yeah, but I just want to know how can I delete the string from the Name.txt which is present in ab variable. :( I am not getting any answer which will delete those values from Name.txt. Please suggst me if that can be done ?

Comment: I can redirect the values in ab variable into another file (for example : echo $ab > test.txt) if this is difficult to achive with variable

Comment: If your `sed` supports the `-i` option then you can use the `sed` variant to do in-place edits.  If you like the `grep` solution, you will need to save to a temporary file and move it over the original, or maybe use Perl.

Comment: But the above solution is not actually DELETING the string which is present in ab from Name.txt, is it?

Comment: sorry, I cant use perl.

Comment: Updated in response to emerging requirements.

Comment: Have u tried this `sed -i "/^\(${ab//,/\|}\)\$/d" Name.txt` ? Did it give the expected result ?

Comment: can u please share with me what is the value of ab and what are the values in abc.txt so that i will try in the same way as this is not working in my example as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49544/discussion-between-tripleee-and-pooja25)

Comment: hey I don't have access to chat, its restricted. Thanks. Out of curiosity I am asking you one more question. As we have implemented this with a variable, can this be done if I have one txt file instead a variable? if yes, how?

Comment: The pastebin link contains exactly the details you asked for.  Yes, it's possible to generate a `sed` script out of a text file; see the many near-duplicate questions.

Comment: See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601163/874188 although it is somewhat tangential.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sed -e 's/\bjyoti\b//g;s/\bpriya\b//g' < Name.txt
```

(using `\b` assuming you need word boundaries)

Comment: but the values in the parameter ab can be different every time. so how this can be put here? Is there any way to put the $ab so that it will pick up all the values from this parameter ?

Comment: Is this possible in sed ?

Answer (score 0):

this will do it:

```
for param in `echo $ab | sed -e 's/[ ]+//g' -e 's/,/ /g'` ; do res=`sed -e "s/$param//g" < name.txt`; echo $res > name.txt; done
echo $res
```

Comment: but its not deleting those params from the Name.txt file. I want to delete the string which is present in ab parameter from abc.txt